# Does Hibernate only support explicit primary keys defined at the database

Tags: hibernate, composite-primary-key

I am working with a legacy database where there are no explicitly defined primary keys defined for the tables. Instead, multiple columns have been used to define the uniqueness constraints for rows in the tables. In short these columns form a composite key and can be viewed as implicit primary keys for the tables. I am thinking of defining a composite key using the columns that define the uniqueness constraints as the primary key for the entity. Will that work in Hibernate? I am concerned that since no primary keys have been defined for the tables, Hibernate will fail when entities are created for these tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate implements the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html), which explicitly permits composite primary keys, as long as they are immutable:

> A primary key corresponds to one or more fields or properties (“attributes”) of the entity class.
>
> - A simple (i.e., non-composite) primary key must correspond to a single persistent field or property of the entity class. The Id annotation or id XML element must be used to denote a simple primary key.
> - A composite primary key must correspond to either a single persistent field or property or to a set of such fields or properties as described be
>   low. A primary key class must be defined to represent a composite primary key. Composite primary keys typically arise when mapping from
>   legacy databases when the database key is comprised of several columns. The
>   EmbeddedId or IdClass annotation is used to denote a composite primary key.

and

> The value of its primary key uniquely identifies an entity instance within a persistence context and to EntityManager operations as described in Chapter 3, “Entity Operations”. The application must not change the value of the primary key. The behavior is undefined if this occurs.

Comment: I understand that composite keys are allowed. My question is that these keys that form the composite have not been specifically defined at the database level i.e. there is no primary key(column1, column2..) etc defined in the create table DDL

Comment: Hibernate does not care about the DDL used to create the table (unless you ask it to create/update the schema on startup). It only issues DML statements, which can not observe a difference between a unique and a primary key constraint.

Comment: The reason I ask this was because when I tried to generate the entities from the tables with NetBeans IDE using Hibernate as the JPA  provider it failed to do so, complaining that the tables did not have primary keys. Thank you very much